# Use of Prior in Hierarchical Query

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I am trying to implement hierarchical query in my project. I have read most of the documents on internet but unable to get information related to use of PRIOR in it.

```
SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,MGR,LEVEL
FROM TMP_PCH
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPNO=MGR
START WITH MGR IS NULL;
```

PRIOR plays significant role in this query but changing the position of PRIOR or Removing it from query gives me a different result.
It would be really helpful if you can help me to understand exact use of this.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hierarchy means, that one row of a table is a "parent", and another one - a "child". `PRIOR` is used to show who is who. Clause `CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPNO = MGR` means, that if two rows have the same value, but one row in a column `EMPNO`, and the second - in a column `MGR`, then second is a "parent" and first is a "child". So, query

```
SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,MGR,LEVEL
FROM TMP_PCH
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPNO = MGR
START WITH MGR = 'John'
```

returns all subordinates of John (and John itself), and query

```
SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,MGR,LEVEL
FROM TMP_PCH
CONNECT BY PRIOR MGR = EMPNO
START WITH MGR = 'John'
```

returns all bosses of John (and John itself).

Answer (score 1):

you can understand `PRIOR` as a reference to the previous hierarchy level.
`PRIOR MGR = EMPNO` means "the manager from the previous level is now the employee", so we are going bottom-up
`PRIOR EMPNO = MGR` means "the employee from the previous level is now the manager", so we are going top-down

when you write it like this `EMPNO = PRIOR MGR`, you can read it as "we go the direction from an employee to his manager"

bottom-up

```
             MGR
PRIOR MGR    EMPNO
PRIOR EMPNO
```

vs top-down

```
PRIOR MGR
PRIOR EMPNO  MGR
             EMPNO
```